# Geoprocessing Service Failed: Could not service request

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service

I have a geoprocessing service that gives a very basic general error:

```
 esriJobMessageTypeInformative: Submitted.
 esriJobMessageTypeInformative: Executing...
 esriJobMessageTypeInformative: Executing (ReportWilliamsTest2): 
 ReportWilliamsTest2
 esriJobMessageTypeInformative: Start Time: Thu Feb 08 10:44:21 2018
 esriJobMessageTypeInformative: Executing (ReportWilliamsTest2): 
 ReportWilliamsTest2
 esriJobMessageTypeInformative: Start Time: Thu Feb 08 10:44:21 2018
 esriJobMessageTypeInformative: Running script ReportWilliamsTest2...
 esriJobMessageTypeInformative: Processing: 1
 esriJobMessageTypeError: Failed.
 esriJobMessageTypeInformative: Could not service request.
```

**Is there any way for me to prompt a better error message from Esri Job Messages?**

(I realize I can print messages to deduce the place my code is failing, but I want to receive more info from ArcGIS Server as to why it could not service the request)

Also, my service runs fine when testing locally.

Answer (score 2):

Set the ArcGIS Server logging level to Debug then run your service. In server manager click on the Logs tab, then settings upper right corner) and then pick Debug from the log level dropdown.

After you run the service query the log messages by setting the Log Filter to "Debug" and the Source dropdown to the name of your geoprocessing service.